# Stack vs. Heap in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, heap-memory, stack-memory

In your actual programming experience, how did this knowledge of STACK and HEAP actually rescue you in real life? Any story from the trenches? Or is this concept good for filling up programming books and good for theory?

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic than a question with a real answer; consider switching this to a wiki.

Comment: It does seem more of a discussion given the answers posted so far. This question can be answered either "Concept not useful", or "Concept useful and *here's an example of how*". "Concept useful" with no specific example doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: see this post talks about the stack and heap for .net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727821/net-stack-and-heap-what-goes-where-when-i-declare-a-string/12728239#12728239

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To me it is the difference between being a "developer/programmer" and a "craftsman". Anyone can learn to write code and see how things just "magically happen" for you not knowing why/how. To really be valuable at what you do, I think there is a great importance to find out as much as you can about the Framework you're using.  Remember it's not just a *language*, it's a Framework that you leverage to create the best application to your abilities.

I've analyzed many memory dumps over the years and found it extremely helpful knowing the internals and differences between the two. Most of these have been OutOfMemory conditions and unstable applications. This knowledge is absolutely necessary to use WinDbg when looking at dumps. When investigating a memory dump, knowing how memory is allocated between the kernel/user-mode process and the CLR can at least tell you where to begin your analysis.

For example, let's take an OOM case:
The allocated memory you see in the Heap Sizes, Working Set, Private Memory, Shared Memory, Virtual Memory, Committed Memory, Handles, and Threads can be a big indicator of where to start.

There about 8 different heaps that the CLR uses:

1. Loader Heap: contains CLR structures and the type system
2. High Frequency Heap: statics, MethodTables, FieldDescs, interface map
3. Low Frequency Heap: EEClass, ClassLoader and lookup tables
4. Stub Heap: stubs for CAS, COM wrappers, P/Invoke
5. Large Object Heap: memory allocations that require more than 85k bytes
6. GC Heap: user allocated heap memory private to the app
7. JIT Code Heap: memory allocated by mscoreee (Execution Engine) and the JIT compiler for managed code
8. Process/Base Heap: interop/unmanaged allocations, native memory, etc

Finding what heap has high allocations can tell me if I have memory fragmentation, managed memory leaks, interop/unmanaged leaks, etc.

Knowing that you have 1MB (on x86)/ 4MB (on x64) of stack space allocated for each thread that your app uses reminds me that if I have 100 threads you will have an additional 100MB of virtual memory usage.

I had a client that had Citrix servers crashing with OutOfMemory problems, being unstable, slow responsiveness when their app was running on it in multiple sessions. After looking at the dump (I didn't have access to the server), I saw that there were over 700 threads being used by that instance of the app! Knowing the thread stack allocation, allowed me to correlate the OOMs were caused by the high thread usage.

In short, because of what I do for my "role", it is invaluable knowledge to have. Of course even if you're not debugging memory dumps it never hurts either!

Comment: I'd just like to add for completeness: While each thread does have a default stack of 1 MiB, it doesn't mean the memory is commited (it isn't, at least not on 64-bit Windows 7 with .NET framework 4). The defaults I've seen are more like 4 kiB commited by default. So it does take 1 MiB of virtual address space, but not 1 MiB of physical memory (be it a page file, other memory mapped file or actual RAM). On a 64-bit system, you can have thousands of stacks and still only take just a few megs of "real" memory. In fact, I've seen the managed heap allocate TiBs, while only committing a few megs.

Comment: Thank you note the need to clarify - I've edited my response to explicitly call out Virtual Memory instead of Committed.

Answer (score 16):

The distinction in .NET between the semantics of reference types and value types, is a much more important concept to grasp.

Personally, I have never bothered thinking about the stack or heap in all my years of coding (just CLR based).

Comment: mmm - It's difficult to understand reference type vs value type semantics (especially the why behind them) without understanding the stack and heap.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be: "Explain why value::reference != stack::heap". :)

Comment: Jon Skeet has already answered that question http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html

Comment: @Reed, I disagree entirely.  Using Heap vs. Stack to explain reference vs. value type semantics generally results in confusion and disinformation.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Reference vs value type has nothing to do with stack and heap. While it's a notion that's repeated even by MSDN in some cases, it's simply false. For example, value types can be stored on the heap (pinned handles, boxing, ...), on the stack, in registers (I've heard so many people say "C# is slow because it's stack based" it's not even funny anymore), the large object heap even. In any case, it's an implementation detail, and if the .NET runtime decides, it can do whatever it wants with the values - that's its job. Stack / heap is about scope (now), not about data types.

Comment: @Luaan I completely understand that - but I do think that you won't get a full understanding of value types (in particular) without understanding how they differ in storage.  Most uses of value types have scoping rules that change how they are stored, and this does have an impact on when things should/could be beneficial to use.

Comment: @ReedCopsey True, but the scoping rules aren't actually something inherent to value types. It's just that implementing scoping rules for value types is trivial if you don't allow (explicit) references to value types. The problem is that the abstraction is incredibly leaky. What about value types that are part of reference types? What about reference types that are parts of value types? References to value types? `stackalloc`'d reference types? Yes, I think it is important to understand the difference. But don't forget it *is* an implementation detail. It *can* change at any moment.

Comment: Excellent articles on the matter discussed above (if you haven't read them already): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 11):

It certainly is helpful to understand the distinction when one is building compilers.

Here are a few articles I've written about how various issues in memory management impact the design and implementation of the C# language and the CLR:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Memory+Management/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it matters if you're just building average business applications, which I think most .NET programmers are.

The books I've seen just mention stack and heap in passing as if memorizing this fact is something of monumental importance.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, this is one of the very few technical questions that I ask every person I'm going to hire.

I feel that it is critical to understanding how to use the .NET framework (and most other languages).  I never hire somebody who doesn't have a clear understanding of memory usage on the stack vs. the heap.

Without understanding this, it's almost impossible to understand the garbage collector, understand .NET performance characteristics, and many other critical development issues.

Comment: I agree with you, but you really didn't provide a good example of what to know about the Stack and Heap. I am interested in learning something new :)

Comment: I agree with leppie, the distinction between a reference and value type is very important, but whether they end up on the stack or heap... you haven't convinced me why it would matter so much.

Comment: Well, I usually ask in general terms, and try to get the candidate to explain the difference to me. This has become one of my benchmarks on the level of understanding - I feel that somebody who knows how the memory allocation in .NET works will at least be willing and able to learn just about anything else required. I think you need to understand 1)The stack, in general terms, 2)The heap, in general terms, 3)How reference types work, 4)How value types work, 5)Argument passing using ref/out, and how it differs from by value, especially with reference types (not stack/heap, but semi-related)

Comment: @Meta-Knight: I agree, that's the practical application of this.  However, I feel that it's nearly impossible to understand WHY reference/value type semantics work the way they do, and especially how the GC works properly, without understanding stack and heap.

Comment: One dissenting voice is Eric Lippert of course, who thinks the distinction between reference and value types is much more than stack versus heap (which he describes as an implementation detail). http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: @Reed Copsey: OK, I agree with you then :-) but I'd rather ask an interview question on reference vs value type than stack vs heap!

Comment: And another dissenting voice in Jon Skeet 'A lot of confusion has been wrought by people explaining the difference between value types and reference types as "value types go on the stack, reference types go on the heap". This is simply untrue' http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html

Comment: I don't believe this actually answers the question.

Comment: @MarkJ: I never disagreed with you.  I was merely pointing out that I think there is a distinction between stack and heap, and I feel that it's an important distinction.  I would agree with everyone saying that ref/value type is more critical, but I don't feel that it's possible to fully understand it without understanding the stack and heap.  I completely agree with Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet's posts - stack != value type, heap != reference type, and that's one of the things I look for people to understand, too.

Comment: @sylvanaar: I was suggesting "Concept useful specifically to get job" ;)  Prior to my current employment, this has been something that's been asked of me, too.  I find that it's a valuable, important thing to understand, because it is required for understanding of many other fundimentals, which my second paragraph was supposed to suggest.

Comment: @reeed: touche - i guess that is one use of it

Comment: @ReedCopsey " I feel that somebody who knows how the memory allocation in .NET works will at least be willing and able to learn just about anything else required"  I haven't on a day to day basis needed to think about stack vs heap, and I haven't had it asked till yesterday almost 2 years in to my career in an interview. After reading this i still do not know what it specifically is.

Comment: @kcbeard It really depends a lot on what you're doing day to day.  I work in technical computing, so memory management and issues relating to it are a near daily concern.  For typical LOB apps, you may never care.  However, I still consider this important knowledge to understand overall, especially since it also plays a large role when dealing with interop code, etc.  Granted, native code makes it more important to understand, as managed code hides a lot of this complexity, but eventually, the lines blur a bit...

Comment: As for understanding Stack vs Heap and memory management in general, this question wasn't about explaining the differences, just knowing where it's useful...

Comment: Yeah i know this question wasn't specific to what is stack and heap, it just was ranked first on Google. But Skeets article helped a lot. I haven't much use of applying that knowledge day to day. But understanding and learning can always benefit me down the road even if i have to hit Google to refresh that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The important distinction is between reference types and value types. It's not true that "value types go on the stack, reference types go on the heap". Jon Skeet has written [about this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html) and so has [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We had a Claim Entity (business Object) which contained data for an entire claim. One of the requirements of the application was to create an audit trail of every single value changed by the user. In order to this without hitting the database twice we would maintain Original Claim Entity in the form and a Working Claim Entity. The Working Claim Entity would get updated when the user clicked Save and we would then compare the Original Claim Entity properties with corresponding Working Claim Entity properties to determine what changed. One day we noticed hey our compare method is never finding a difference. This is where my understanding of the Stack and Heap saved my rear end (specifically value types vs reference types). Because we needed to maintain to copies of the same object in memory the developer simply created two objects

```
Dim originalClaim As ClaimBE
Dim workingClaim As ClaimBE
```

then called the business layer method to return the claim object and assigned the same claimBE to both variables

```
originalClaim = BLL.GetClaim()
workingClaim = originalClaim
```

hence two reference types pointing to the same value type. Nightmare averted.

Comment: Your story has nothing to do stack vs. heap; it is only value vs. reference. As others have stated, value types have the distinction of being able to be stored on the stack, but that is where the relationship ends. Whether `originalClaim` and `workingClaim` were stored on the stack or heap is irrelevant to your story.

Comment: @Gabe Even funnier, reference types can also go on stack. It does not happen often (one example is the `stackalloc` keyword in unsafe context), but that might change in future versions of .NET if it's ever deemed worth the trouble - this would be a huge help when doing allocation heavy operations that only use the allocated objects inside a given scope - no need to put that on the heap for the GC to collect later, just use stack, push, pop, done, no GC needed.