# .NET stack and heap, what goes where when I declare a string?

Tags: c#, .net

If I execute this line I create a string which is a reference.

```
string mystring = "Hello World"
```

Is variable `mystring` in the same context as the object I declare it? And the data `"Hello World"` on the heap?

Comment: string literals are interned

Comment: @Jodrell - afaik interned strings are also kept on the (or: a) heap. So that doesn't really change the situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Official Answer:](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/) it's an implementation detail and you don't need to know.

It is of course knowable for a specific (current) version of the framework:

1. if this is inside a method, then `mystring` is a reference variable, usually on the stack. But when it is captured by a lambda, or when the method is async, or ... it is moved to the heap.
2. if this is inside a class, then each instance will contain a `mystring` reference as a field, stored on the heap.

In both cases there is an anonymous string object on the heap containing `"Hello World"`

Comment: If you're going to call it an official answer a reference would be great

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Answer (score 5):

It's complicated.
First of all the strings are interned by the compiler, so your string could be a reference to a previously allocated string object.
Second of all it is an implementation detail, which you shouldn't worry about, and which can change at any of the next C#/.NET versions.
I'll refer you to the excellent post by  Eric Lippert, who is one of the people who write the C# compiler: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Read these... From Eric Lippert...  he wrote the C# compiler!  Should answer all your questions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: Both links are not active