# How many instances of string will be created in the code snippet for C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, string

How many instances of string will be created in the following code snippets for C#.Net

**Snippet 1**

```
    public void TestFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

**Snippet 2** (used local constant for "Hello World")

```
    public void TestFunction()
    {
        const string someString = "Hello World";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(someString);
        }
    }
```

Will it create 1000 instances in snippet1 and 1 instance in snippet 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET stack and heap, what goes where when I declare a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727821/net-stack-and-heap-what-goes-where-when-i-declare-a-string)

Comment: You might want to read https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/what-is-string-interning/

Comment: `const` is efficently `static` (there's no use of creating *several* **constant** values one per each instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Snippets will create 1 instance of the string.

Snippet one will only have one instance of the string because of something called [String interning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/)

Essentially .Net is clever enough to not create unnecessary versions of the same string.

> If you have two identical string literals in one compilation unit then the code we generate ensures that only one string object is created by the CLR for all instances of that literal within the assembly. This optimization is called "string interning".

In Snippet 2 only 1 instance is created because it is marked as const which means that value is constant, it cannot be changed and it is by definition static so you don't have to mark it static. It actually hard codes this value into the Intermediate language the C# compiles into.